# why does class constructor need to be set explicitly

Tags: javascript

Have a look at the below code ::

```
Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super    = this.prototype;
    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing  = true;

    var prototype = new this();
    initializing  = false;


    function Class() {

    }

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;  

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;  
    // why is this defined explicitly ?? i don't make sense to me ? 

    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    return Class;
  };
```

The above code is a design pattern used by John Resig for a plugin called spritz.js now there is this line in the code, see below ::

```
Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
```

what is this line for? I don't quite get it.

does the constructor really needs to be set explicitly? The comment says the following,

```
// Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
```

But what if that line has not been added, what are the repercussions? Can somebody explain ?

Comment: Try taking it out and see what it does. Create a new "class" and see what it's `constructor` property is.

Comment: Also, did you copy your question from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033208)?

Comment: @Mathletics , i tried and failed and so i ask here on SO . i know the vertues of debugging !